# Spree Forgot password

Tags: spree, spree-auth-devise

I've installed spree on my app and have currently running live.

On my local machine the app seems to work fine and when I try to use forgot password I go to the confirmation page. But on my live server, I get the error 500 screen.

I Installed the spree mailer gem for my backed and put in the smpth information, but when I try to test it I get the following error (The change you wanted was rejected.
Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to.)

Can anyone tell me how to setup the spree mail and forgotten passwords?

Comment: Try to look into log file. One of my client had the same issue and it was because of wrong settings for SMTP account.

Comment: @Jakub If you want I can add the log file? I've checked it myself and I don't see any abnormality. No errors at al.

Comment: If that's 500 error and you don't see anything in log file it might be hard to guess. Maybe Nginx/Apache tells more?

Comment: @Jakub He Jakub, sorry for the late response have been on a holiday. Concerning the log. I checked the log again and actually found. `[2018-03-05T10:29:39.064306 #6774]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1095ms (ActiveRecord: 44.6ms)
F, [2018-03-05T10:29:39.065964 #6774] FATAL -- : 
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname "www.volksphone.nl" does not match the server certificate):
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:315:in post_connection_check'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted server provider and they added a server certificated to my mail server resolving the problem.